# How to pronounce dark L?

Tags: pronunciation

I have been practicing dark L.
I saw this video from Youtube about pronouncing dark L. Could you please watch it at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BygKFtLVBbQ?
However, I wonder American English speakers pronounce Dark L like this video or not.

Comment: I think there's some variation in how AmE speakers pronounce their Ls.  When I pronounce an L, the tip of my tongue never touches the roof of my mouth.  (Does this make me weird?  I don't know.)  In IPA, I think this means I have [ʟ] rather than [l] or [ɫ].

Comment: Ah, I found [this answer](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/539/2081) on linguistics.se, which says: "Normally you should also notice, in a subsequent phase, that the tip of your tongue touches the front of your palate closer to the teeth, but since you already mentioned that you tend to finish your "dark Ls" with a "w" sound, **it is possible that this part is absent in your pronunciation - which is actually quite common in America** for instance." (emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I ever heard some AmE speakers don't let the tip of their tongue to the roof of their mouth but I have to choose only one way to pronounce because it's not easy to pronounce in many ways.

Comment: Do American's pronounce the "l" in palm and salt? I ask because in the video he gave these words as examples. I do not pronounce the "l" in either of these words,  if I speak fairly fast it comes out: /pɑːm/ and /sɔːt/.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think some do.  You may be interested in the discussion here: http://aschmann.net/AmEng/#PronunciationOfAlm  (If it doesn't load the right section, click on *The Pronunciation of “alm” and “olk” and “alk”*.)

Comment: @snailboat Gasp!So many tiny words, where are my glasses? :) Still very interesting, I never knew that some pronounce the "l" in almond, I remember as a child saying that word as "olmend" and being ticked off by an uncle. I was mortified!

Answer (score 3):

Prof: Balazer's video describes the mechanics correctly. To  my ear, he over-articulates, giving the impression of a very old-school "elocution" teacher; but this may in fact be desirable for beginning students.

OP finds that the teacher, "Rachel", in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtY4-AmEcJc) speaks too fast for his comfort; but students with more experience listening to American English may find her video useful. She speaks more naturally than Prof. Balazer, and she describes the subtleties of actual American speech more precisely. "Rachel"has many videos on YouTube, and I have found all of those I have seen accurate and "student-friendly", with non-technical language.

Comment: Thank you so much StoneyB for your help and watching the video. Your recommend is really useful. I ever seen the video that you recommended few days ago too but for me, the speaker spoke very fast and it was too difficult to see how she pronounced.

Comment: @nkm Ah, then you would do well to work with Prof. Balazer's video until you are more comfortable. Perhaps I have done him an injustice, and he is right to speak very slowly and precisely for beginners. I will edit my answer to reflect your observations.

Comment: Yes, Prof. Balazer spoke very slowly and I could see very well how he moved his tongue when he pronounced final L sound and it was easy to learn and do like him. However, I ever pronounced like that to an American too, he said I over pronounced too. That's why I asked here that Prof. Balazer's video was correct or not.  Right now I understand Prof.Balazer's video describes the mechanics correctly but for myself I have to keep practing to be more natural. Thank you so much for your answer. It's really helpful.

Comment: I can't help feeling Prof. Balazer's video is reminiscent of [the blind leading the blind](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+blind+leading+the+blind). Maybe there's some subtle advantage to being taught by someone who learn English himself later in life, but I can't see it. He'd certainly never pass for a "native speaker".

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, he's a [native speaker](http://englishpronunciation4all.com/), just a very old one, of a very old school of speech instruction (I've worked with others of that generation, and earlier ones). And it appears that he's an autodidact, which always plucks up my eyebrows. Check out [this page](http://englishpronunciation4all.com/NewVoicedConsonants.html)

Comment: His "accent" has been [asked about on ELU before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53081/). So far as I (or anyone else on that earlier question) can see, his website doesn't explicitly say he's a native speaker of English, and frankly I find it hard to believe he could be. But what do I know? Native speakers from South Africa, for example, don't always sound completely kosher to me. All I can say is that although as a Brit I'm supposed to hear more dialectal variation than most Anglophones, I don't find his speech all that easy to understand, for all that he speaks painfully slowly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 5th paragraph: "Leonard Balazer is a native speaker of American English with degrees in physics and engineering." And answer at ELU reports he's a Michigander. Believe it or not, that's how "Speech" was once taught in many US high schools. ... But a **lot** of it is age. "Painfully" is the *mot juste*.

Comment: That's [2:0](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116219/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-blood-dimmed-tragedy-and-how-does-it-pass-curr/116223#comment237031_116223) to you already today. I must look out for some context where I can actually be *right* for a change. (actually, I just wanted to do that to see if I could make a link to a specific *comment!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's OK. You're the main guy making me rewrite my answers--about one in three, I think. And you're the author of the Best Line Ever on ELL: "don’t use Past Perfect unless you really have to." I quote that at least once a week.

Comment: For Rachel's video, I understand what she said but I could catch her pronounce, she didn't open her mouth wide. For Prof. Balazer, he speaks very slowly and open his mouth wide so it's easy to learn to pronounce from him. It's the same way that parents teach their children to speak. It's important way to teach about speaking and pronunciation.

Comment: I have not learned a foreign language for 50 years; but I often had to learn dialects as an actor, and I always found it easiest to copy models by listening **and immediate repetition at full speed**: that way you give yourself immediate feedback. [This answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6245/32) to another question seems to suggest the same technique.

Comment: @ StoneyB: I don't remember learning to speak English, obviously, but I never actually learnt how to *speak* French at school in the UK (I could read & write it well enough to pass exams). I only finally got the hang of speaking French (at "normal" speed) when I lived in a French monastery for a couple of weeks. I'd already been a uni student in France for three months by then, but picked up very little because all the native students wanted to practice their English with me (the monks weren't supposed to talk beyond necessity, but they figured that didn't count with foreigners like me! :)

Comment: yes, I want to immediate repetition at full speed from movies too but I don't have enough time.

Comment: Thank you StoneyB and FumbleFingers for your comments. For me, my young child can't speak correctly some Thai consonants or vowels. I'm Thai and I have to say those sounds very slowly, open my mouth wide more than usual and show him to see how my tongue works. It's over pronunciation but it works. My son could pronounce difficult sounds correctly. After speaking often, he has natural sounds. For me, final L sound in English is the most difficult. However, I understand teaching pronunciation by opening mouth wide throug Youtube is not beautyful. ^^